# php preg_match using shorthand and character class combined

Tags: regex, shorthand, character-class

```
echo preg_match( '/\d[A-Z]/', 'CD' ); // Displays “0”
```

How can it display 0 when clearly there are characters that match the range "[A-Z]"?

Is it the way the parsing occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/\d[A-Z]/` says that the input must have a digit first, and then an alphabet must be present.

Since the input `CD` doesnot contain a digit and an alphabet following it, the function returns 0.
To match more than one capital letters or digits, you can use the following regex.

```
/[\dA-Z]+/
```

Comment: I realized what you said after some examination and deep thought of the expression.

Comment: well am glad that you finally understood.